# Unable to patch projects with Jailcoder

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I'd want to do some tests of an iOS app I'm developing concerning jailbroken devices, so I patched an Xcode. Since JailCoder seems to haven't been updated since quite time ago, I'm testing on an older Xcode version (4.6.2), that seems to be successfully patched. However, when I try to patch the project, JailCoder interface says 'Error'. Is somebody experiencing the same?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com) instead?  It's still being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Try on xCode 4.6.3 with [JailCoder 1.2.1](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/). You also need to have [AppSync](http://www.appaddict.org/forum/index.php?/topic/6-installing-appsync/) installed on your iDevice in order to install apps from xCode (with JailCoder). There might be an issue with code signing (if you are experiencing any errors there), in case the xCode Patch didn't work properly. Lastly, make sure to follow anything the [developers suggest](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/guide.php?lang=en-US). Working perfectly on my Mac at the moment with the version mentioned above.